# Is there a elegant javascript equivalent of this python code using formatting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join, formatting

Is there a javascript equivalent of this python code? I know you can use ``, but how can you combine it with ... spread operator?

```py
'{}{}{} {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}'.format(*array)
```

array is list of length 10 of numbers, the result expected is something like

```py
'123 456-7890'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace by shifting the array values.

```js
const
    format = (pattern, [...array]) =>
        pattern.replace(/\{\}/g, Array.prototype.shift.bind(array));

console.log(format('{}{}{} {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]));
```